# POST request is working using POSTMAN, but when I'm trying to call the same link using Axios from browser(UI) it's showing 404 error | node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, postman

[Error message received in colnsole (404 Error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb8oz.png)

[Using POSTMAN successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzdbI.png)

Api Call -

```
useEffect(() => {
    ticketConfirmationApi.getBookedPassengersDetails(transactionId)
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(data => {
            // console.log("Data from mongoDB PassengeDetails")
            // console.log(data)
            setBookedPassengers(data)
        })
    ticketConfirmationApi.getBookingHistory(transactionId)
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(data => {
            // console.log("Data from mongoDB History")
            // console.log(data)
            setBookingHistory(data)
        })
}, [])
```

API -

```
import axios from 'axios'
export function getBookedPassengersDetails(transactionId) {
    let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/passengers/get-passengers/tid'
    return axios.post(apiUrl, transactionId)
}
export function getBookingHistory(transactionId) {
    let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/booking-history/get-history/tid'
    return axios.post(apiUrl, transactionId)
}
```

Post request -

it is saved in the js file named passengers.js

```
.post('/get-passengers/tid', async (req, res, next) => {
        PassengerDetails.find({ transactionId: req.body.transactionId }, (err, foundData) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                res.status(500).send()
            } else {
                if (foundData.length === 0) {
                    res.status(404).send("No data available")
                } else {
                    console.log(foundData)
                    res.json(foundData)
                }
            }
        })
    })
```

it is saved in the js file named booking-history.js

```
.post("/get-history/tid", (req, res, next) => {
        try{
            BookingHistory.find({ transactionId: req.body.transactionId }, (err, foundData) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    res.status(500).send()
                } else {
                    if (foundData.length === 0) {
                        res.status(404).send("No data available")
                    } else {
                        console.log(foundData)
                        res.json(foundData)
                    }
                }
            })
        }catch (err) {
            console.log("Some error occured : " + err)
        }
    })
```

What I'm trying to do is getting the details using the "transactionId", but the code is working when using postman this shows that the link provided is fine, don't know why it's not working when calling through the browser(UI).

Comment: What is the value of the `transactionId` in the client side code? What is the value of `req.body.transactionId` in the server side code? You really need to do some basic debugging here.

Comment: Your server side code is conditionally returning 404 based on the data in the body. This is an error. The URL itself identifies a resource. It shouldn't conditionally be 404 or not based on anything else.

Comment: Problem solved: In the API section, the parameter "transactionId" should be of type Object, i.e.  - {transactionId}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: In the API section, the parameter "transactionId" should be of type Object, i.e. - {transactionId}

```
import axios from 'axios'
export function getBookedPassengersDetails(**{transactionId}**) {
    let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/passengers/get-passengers/tid'
    return axios.post(apiUrl, transactionId)
}
export function getBookingHistory(**{transactionId}**) {
    let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/booking-history/get-history/tid'
    return axios.post(apiUrl, transactionId)
}
```